# DataGridView row_onclick event?

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, event-handling, row

I have a DataGridView and I should handle an event when a row (or any cell of a row) is clicked, yet I can't find anything like this. Is there a way to do this other than having each individual cell a handler method?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What you mean exactly with "having each individual cell a handler method"? You know that the cell-related events are assigned to the DataGridView as a whole and triggered by each single cell, don't you? Also what have you tried?

Comment: Is there something wrong with the solutions [here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=datagridview%20row%20selection%20event)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the SelectionChanged event of Datagridview.

You have to set the **SelectionMode** property to **FullRowSelect** and check any change in the above event.

If necessary, you can get the rowindex using *Datagridview.CurrentCell.Rowindex* too.